# I wonder about .htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php/$1/$2/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php/$1/$2/$3/$4 [L]
```

you can see my code..

$1/$2/$3/$4 .. (now)

$1/$2/$3/$4/$5 ~ $unlimited (I wanted)

sorry my bad english..

do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

If you want unlimited `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/`'s, you could just match for `[a-zA-Z0-9_-/]+` and call it a day:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^([/a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, the first `/` was in the wrong place, try it now. Also make sure you have the rest of your conditions above it (replacing only the Rules)

Comment: Thanks to you I find a way / RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] /